# php filemtime, filectime, fileatime shows different value

Tags: php

So I have retrieved the filectime, filemtime and fileatime from a file. and insert the value into DB.
but the values inserted into DB are different with the one showed in file explorer.

[image: the value inserted into DB]

[image: the value showed in file explorer]

I'm not sure how to address this issue. The code I use as below:

```
 $lastaccess=mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',fileatime($path)));
        $lastmod =mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',filemtime($path)));
        $itime =mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',filectime($path)));
```

FYI we are GMT+8 here...we only use mamp server (localhost)

Comment: Before saving db, check `var_dump(array($lastaccess, $lastmod, $itime))`

Comment: hi, the values are different from the file explorer view and var_dump

Comment: You configure timezone in PHP with date_default_timezone_set()?