# PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator doesn't get all files in ext.HDD on Mac OSx (ONLY)

Tags: php, macos

I have a PHP file that run through the path (which is manually enter by user), search all the files inside that path and get their information (size, date, etc). The information will be inserted into DB. I attached the sample picture here: [php filemtime, filectime, fileatime shows different value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610425/php-filemtime-filectime-fileatime-shows-different-value)

Now, on a Windows PC, whether the path is from an external HDD, the script runs perfectly on my PC. Problem is my client PC is using Mac OS X. He can run the script if the path belongs to internal HDD, but somehow, when he uses ext.hdd, he only get these information:

[image]

He said the PHP script didn't capture other files. Is that even possible? I mean, in Windows OS the script runs fine, be it internal drive or external drive.

Does `RecursiveIteratorIterator` capture hidden files too?

**EDIT:**

Here is my code:

```
$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($p);
    $Directory->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
    foreach($objects as $path => $object){
    clearstatcache();
         $infos=array();
         $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $filesize=mysql_real_escape_string(filesize($path));
        $lastaccess=mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',fileatime($path)));
        $lastmod =mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',filemtime($path)));
        $itime =mysql_real_escape_string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',filectime($path)));
        $filetype =mysql_real_escape_string(filetype($path));
        $fileowner=mysql_real_escape_string(fileowner($path));
        $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
        if(!isset($path_parts['extension'])) {  
            $ext='directory';                
        } else {                
            $ext=mysql_real_escape_string($path_parts['extension']);
        }

        $dirname=mysql_real_escape_string($path_parts['dirname']);
        $basename=mysql_real_escape_string($path_parts['basename']);
        $filename=mysql_real_escape_string($path_parts['filename']);
        $inode=mysql_real_escape_string(fileinode($path));

        $path=mysql_real_escape_string($path);

        $queries = $this->dbQuery("insert into directory_listing(Path,  Filesize, Last_Access, Last_Modified, File_Type, Directory_Name, Basename, Filename, Extension,File_Inode, Inode_Changed_Time, File_Owner) values ('".$path."','".$filesize." bytes','".$lastaccess."','".$lastmod."','".$filetype."', '".$dirname."', '".$basename."','".$filename."','".$ext."', '".$inode."', '".$itime."','".$fileowner."')");

    }
    $this->getDirectory();
```

Now, my prob is, I can run this code in my Windows 7 PC using `localhost` (client is also using `localhost` but MAMP on Mac OS X, mine is XAMPP if it does matter).

**EDIT**

The client said he entered this path format: Volumes/[partition name]

**EDIT**

We tried on few ext.HDD, only one of them can be 'read' with the above code...

**EDIT**

The code works if we put '/Volumes/[partition_name]/[somefile_in_partition]' as path

Comment: Is the script executing as a user that has privilege for all files?

Comment: provide code of the script and someone might be able to help

Comment: `RecursiveIteratorIterator` itself has nothing to do with filesystems whatsoever. Show some code.

Comment: @MarkBaker Hi, yes he should have the privelege?

Comment: @Dukeatcoding Hi I edited my post. Prob is the script run OK in my windows PC, be it internal or external drive,,,but client's is macosx, and it works on his local mac internal drive, but nope for ext.hdd

Comment: @deceze Hi, yes, I edited my post.  Prob is the script run OK in my windows PC, be it internal or external drive,,,but client's is macosx, and it works on his local mac internal drive, but nope for ext.hdd

Comment: what exactly path do you enter as $p, when you use it with macos ?

Comment: @Dukeatcoding Hi, I just asked the client, he said "Volumes/[partition_name']"

Comment: @MarkBaker Hi, the logged user is an administrator. And only one ext HDD we tried (from dozen of them) can be read by the php code above (edited post). Is there any other requirement? thanks!